# How to disable 'psfile' processing in dvips?

Tags: dvips

Is it possible to disable figure processing while generating ps-file
from dvi-file?
That is, how to do that dvips will produce the same output when figure file
exists as when figure file does not exist? ("dvips: Could not find
figure file xxx; continuing.")

In `info dvips` it is said:

> Dvips includes some headers on its own initiative, to implement
>   features such as PostScript font reencoding, bitmap font downloading,
>   handling of '\special''s, and so on.  These standard headers are the
>   '.pro' files (for "prologue") in the installation directory
>   '$(psheaderdir)'; they are created from the '.lpro' ("long prologue")
>   files in the distribution by stripping comments, squeezing blank lines,
>   etc., for maximum efficiency.  If you want to peruse one of the standard
>   header files, read the '.lpro' version.

[Here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipsk/special.lpro?view=co) is the .lpro file for `\special`.
Can it be changed to skip `psfile` command?

NOTE: using `-R2` is not sufficient - it works only for absolute and ..-relative paths

Answer (score 1):

Just process dvi file in another directory which does not have the graphics:

```
DIR=$(mktemp -d -p /tmp XXXXXXXXXX)
cp file.dvi $DIR
cd $DIR
dvips file
cd -
cp $DIR/file.ps .
rm -fr $DIR
```